# Split a string in an Arraylist in Java into substring of letters

Tags: java, string, arraylist, split, substring

I have two classes Reader and Tokenizer. I want to split Strings in Wlist Arraylist from the Reader class in tokenizer class. Splitting must be done based on odd and even length of the String.

Ex: If string is "teacher", as its length is odd it should be split into three parts "te", "ac", "her".

If string is even like "cattle" it should be split in 3 parts "ca", "tt", "le".

**Reader Class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Reader {

    String[] wordList = {"Printer", "Airport", "Painter", "Letter",
                         "vehicle", "Teacher"};

    String[] SentenceList = {"Device made to waste ink and paper","Platform for Commercial air transport",
                             "Someone who uses colors and brushes","a written type of communication sent by mail",
                             "Thing used to travel via land","A person who teaches"};

    ArrayList<String> Wlist = new ArrayList<>(6);
    public ArrayList<String> wordCheck(){

        for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
            if((wordList[i] != null) && (!wordList[i].equals("")) && (wordList[i].matches("^[a-zA-Z]*$"))
                    && (wordList[i].length()>4)) {
                //System.out.println("Array does satisfy the required criteria");
                Wlist.add(wordList[i].toUpperCase());
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Array does NOT satisfy the required criteria");
                break;
            }
        }
        //System.out.println(Wlist);
        return Wlist;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getWord(){
        return wordCheck();
    }
    public ArrayList<String> Sentence(){
        ArrayList<String> Slist = new ArrayList<>(6);
        for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
            Slist.add(SentenceList[i]);
        }
        //System.out.println(Slist);
        return Slist;
    }

}




// This is the updated Tokenizer class
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Tokenizer {
    Reader rd = new Reader();
    ArrayList<String> SplList = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<String> splitString() {
        ArrayList<String> Wlist = rd.getWord();
        //String[] result = new String[(Wlist.get().length()+2)/3];
        for(int i=0;i<Wlist.size();i++){
                SplList.add(Arrays.toString(Wlist.get(i).split("(?<=\\\\G..)(?=..)")));

        }

        System.out.println(SplList);
        return SplList;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what question do you have? Your question did not actually ask anything. Please edit the question to describe what is going wrong or other problem you face, and where you think the problem lies. It might help to include output from an example run, and expected output.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer My bad I didn't clarify my question earlier. So, I want to take a Single string at a time from the Wlist Arraylist<String> from Reader class into the Tokenizer class and split it into 3 parts(Ex: teacher will be "te", "ac", "her"). If the String has even length(Ex: 6) it should be split into 3 parts equally(i.e 2 letters each). If the string has odd length(Ex: 7) it has to be split into 3 parts where the last part has 3 letters as given in example for String "teacher".

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Maybe think a little more about the problem first before writing any code, as there are multiple ways to solve your problem.  Would sorting into two lists of even and odd words make it easier to manage?  If so, how would you go about sorting them?  How are you defining a word?  If is it based on length, is "to" a word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking how to split a string into pairs of letters, with any remainder left with the last split:

```
String[] parts = str.split("(?<=\\G..)(?=..)");
```

which achieves your goal (see below).

The split matches *between* these two look arounds:

- `(?<=\\G..)` two chars after the end of the last match
- `(?=..)` there are (at least) two chars after

---

```
String[] wordList = {"Printer", "Airport", "Painter", "Letter", "vehicle", "Teacher"};
List<String[]> splitWords = Arrays.stream(wordList).map(s -> s.split("(?<=\\G..)(?=..)")).collect(toList());
splitWords.forEach(a -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a)));
```

Output:

```
[Pr, in, ter]
[Ai, rp, ort]
[Pa, in, ter]
[Le, tt, er]
[ve, hi, cle]
[Te, ac, her]
```

Comment: I tried this but its asking me to convert Wlist into SplList.add(Arrays.toString(Wlist.get(i).split("(?<=\\\\G..)(?=..)"))) and after I convert it, its giving me an output as: [PRINTER], [AIRPORT], [PAINTER], [LETTER], [VEHICLE], [TEACHER]]

Comment: @coder107 see complete code added to answer

Comment: thank you for your help I was able to solve the issue and split the string.